# Is there a way to use \p{Punct} in a regex(java), but without the "(",")" characters?

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to use `\p{Punct}` in a regex in java, but without the two characters `(` and `)` ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
[\p{Punct}&&[^()]]
```

What this is saying is:

> The `punct` character class except for `(` and `)`.

The `^` character specifies a negative character class.  The `&&` is an intersection between the `punct` class and the custom class for the parenthesis.

Have a look at the [`Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) Javadocs for more info.

Comment: Same exact regex, 4 seconds apart. I like that `:P`

Answer (score 14):

This should work:

```
[\p{Punct}&&[^()]]
```

`&&` is the intersection operator for character classes, so the intersection of `\p{Punct}` and `[^()]` is what you're after. See [Character Classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cc).