# Regex how to match all punctuations but exclude some conditions

Tags: java, regex

I can use `\p{Punct}` to match all punctuations(including underscore).

And I wanted to **exclude** all apostrophes strictly inside a word. For this I'm using `(?<=[a-zA-Z])'(?=[a-zA-Z])`

However I couldn't have them work together to match all punctuations except apostrophes strictly inside a word.

What should I use?

---

examples:

`my brother's` this should not match.

`my brothers'` this should match.

`my 'brother'` these should match.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279694/is-there-a-way-to-use-ppunct-in-a-regexjava-but-without-the-charac) solves your problem. You only need now is `[\p{Punct}&&[^']]`.

Comment: @noob thanks. but this seems to match all `'` instead of only `'` that are strictly inside two letters.

Comment: Few valid and invalid examples would be helpful.

Comment: You may want to consider apostrophes at *one* end of a word, eg `'twas the night before Christmas` and `Davey Jones' locker` etc, but (probably) not `He said 'Hello'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine three conditions here.

1. Match all punctuation except apostrophe `'` using `[\p{Punct}&&[^']]`
2. Match all apostrophe not followed by a letter.
3. Match all apostrophe not preceded by a letter.

**Regex:** `[\p{Punct}&&[^']]|(?<![a-zA-Z])'|'(?![a-zA-Z])`

**Explanation:**

- `[\\p{Punct}&&[^']]` excludes apostrophe from punctuation class.
- `(?<![a-zA-Z])'` matches apostrophe not preceded by a letter.
- `'(?![a-zA-Z])` matches the apostrophe not followed by a letter.

Comment: Hi. thanks for explaining but you seems to misunderstood my objective. I wanted to match all punctuations **except** those `'` that are strictly inside a word. I've provided some examples. Thanks.

Comment: @AntonZ: Yes I did. I thought you want to match it. Now it's clear so I updated my answer. This will be helpful.

Comment: @AntonZ: Now you also know how to include _apostrophe only appearing between letters_.

Answer (score 0):

You could group all punctuations, you are interested in, manually and exclude the apostrophe. Then combine that group with your rule for finding the right apostrophes (that are not within a word) by an OR.

Comment: [Let regex engine do all the work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279694/is-there-a-way-to-use-ppunct-in-a-regexjava-but-without-the-charac).